# Char & between two strings while rendering in HTML isn't working

Tags: html, vbscript, string-concatenation

I am trying to concatenate two strings with a `&` in between them and render it in HTML.

Say for example, I want to get: `Richard & Mary`. I tried `"Richard" & Chr(38) & "Mary"` in the VBScript. It prints `Richard & Mary` when I do the `MsgBox`, but while rendering in HTML it always prints `RichardMary`.

Is there anything I am missing? I searched online and other places but none of them helped me.
Referred this-
http://eyeontesting.com/questions/10262/how-to-concatenate-two-strings-with-the-newline-ch.html

Comment: Try with `"Richard" & "&amp;" & "Mary"`

Comment: & is a special character in html and xml documents. Need to use their escape sequences. I am personally not an html expert bu can you try the escape sequences in the below link and let me know if it is useful. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Comment: @MCND- it shows- RichardAMPMary

Comment: Can you open the html file in a text editor and see what text is stored in tag? Please paste it here

Comment: Also post a more representative sample of your code.

Comment: How are you writing out the HTML? And what exactly does the final HTML look like?

Comment: I cannot have control over that html, its a 3rd party application